# public/system symlink issue in deployment - capistrano

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, rvm, capistrano

In deployment, current folder has public/system and shared folder has system. And it is causing some issues.

1. Just want to understand, what creates public/system? I have gone through the code and couldn't find out what piece of code creates it.
2. Also, Is there a way to restrict in creating the public/system?

There are lot of issues and solutions based on the problem over the internet. But there is no one answer which helps in understanding the cause of the problem.

Comment: What are the specific issues that this is causing?

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano 2 creates a symlink from `current/public/system` to `shared/system` during the `finalize_update` task based on the value of `shared_children`.

Preventing it's creation may not be the right solution to the issues you are having.